# Scroll a UITableView inside a tableViewCell

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I have a custom cell, and add a viewController as a subview to that cell:

```
TestViewController *vc = [[TestViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TestViewController" bundle:nil];
[self addSubview:vc.view];
```

The new viewController has a tableView in it. When I try to scroll that tableView, the base tableView, where the custom cell lives, is being scrolled.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How does this relate to `xcode IDE` or `C`?

Comment: I am not sure it can be done and I don't think it would be a good user experience, but I would say have you set your `delegate` for the `UITableView` in the cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would advice against embedding tableviews however if you really want to do it that way, the solution would probably be to implement the `hitTest` method on the base `tableView` :

```
-(UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //here you will need to check if the point lies within any of the 
    //child tableviews and return it .. else return the super method

    if ([self pointInChildTable:point]) {
        return [self childTableForPoint:point];
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```

note that `pointInChildTable` and `childTableForPoint` should probably be the same method that returns a dictionary with the results. I separated them for explanation only.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Totally agree that embedding the `UITableView` isn't a good idea, but like the idea of the `hitTest: withEvent:` so +1.